# Chrome javascript bind function inconsistency

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-5, google-chrome-devtools

If I browse to about:blank, open the script console and type the following:

```
var x = function() {
    console.info(this.toString() + ' -- ' + arguments.length.toString());
};
x.bind;
```

The response shows that x.bind is implemented in native code:

```
function bind() { [native code] }
```

However, when I pull up the script console on a page of my web app and execute the same statements, it looks like x.bind is not natively impplemented:

```
function (a){var b=this;return function(){b.apply(a,arguments)}}
```

What would cause this implementation to switch like this?  Is there potentially something I'm setting in my javascript that could cause this?  I'm using jQuery on the page - would that have an impact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not jQuery, but some other libraries/scripts add `bind` to `Function.prototype`, and some of them do it without checking if it's already there, happily overwriting the native implementation. I assume you must be using some other script (besides jQuery) on the page, and that other script (whether it's a jQuery plug-in or whatever) is overwriting without checking.

I've just tested in Chrome, and regardless of whether I have jQuery loaded or not, from within an actual page looking at a function's `bind` property shows the native code marker. (In contrast, if I load the latest Prototype, it overwrites Chrome's native version with its own.)

[Example with page with no libraries](http://jsbin.com/ozozex), output on Chrome:

```
Prototype not loaded
jQuery not loaded
function bind() { [native code] }
```

[Example with page with latest jQuery](http://jsbin.com/ozozex/2), output on Chrome:

```
Prototype not loaded
jQuery found: 1.6.2
function bind() { [native code] }
```

[Example with page with latest Prototype](http://jsbin.com/ozozex/3), output on Chrome:

```
Prototype found: 1.7
jQuery not loaded
function bind(context) { if (arguments.length < 2 && Object.isUndefined(arguments[0])) return this; var __method = this, args = slice.call(arguments, 1); return function() { var a = merge(args, arguments); return __method.apply(context, a); } }
```

From your example, you're not loading the latest Prototype, but *something* is overwriting `Function.prototype.bind`.

Comment: Thank you!  You're absolutely right - I found a script on my page that is replacing bind.